# GAE Golang - log.Print()?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, go

Where can one read logs created by calling function:

```
log.Print("Message")
```

The tab "Logs" under Main seems to only display information about what URLs were called, but without any debug information that would be displayed by the application.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/requests#Go_Logging), you should use the `Context` interface to log instead of `log`, if you want your logs to show up in the console.

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
c.Infof("Requested URL: %v", r.URL)
```

Comment: should the Context be passed around, or should a new one be created as needed?

Comment: @NickSiderakis It doesn't currently really matters since it is cached by the SDK both in [development](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-go/source/browse/appengine_internal/api_dev.go#197) and production.

Comment: What happens if you are debugging a function without a request URL!?

Comment: @hendry on App Engine every function call is somehow originating from an HTTP request, do you have a specific example where you find it not to be the case?

Comment: ```func initFrontend() {
 log.Println("Initializing frontend webserver....")
 err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
 }
}```

thats an example where logging will be needed outside of http context. I am also wondering the same thing, how should i change the log call in this case.

Comment: For debugging during development, you can use panic() to see if you got there. For proper logging, you'll need a request somehow.

Comment: Logging outside a request context is not possible in any App Engine runtime. The system only supports logs associated with a request.

Comment: That’s sad. My `init` function loads some data from JSON and I want to debug that. No request is made until that point…

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the new App Engine package [google.golang.org/appengine](https://github.com/golang/appengine), in the README:

> - Logging methods that were on `appengine.Context` are now functions in `google.golang.org/appengine/log`

So you should use

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
log.Infof(c, "Requested URL: %v", r.URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The same context object must be passed around in other method calls.
Here is an example:

```
func handleSign(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {   
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        writeError(c, err)
        return
    }
}

func writeError(c appengine.Context, err os.Error) {
    c.Errorf("%v", err)
}
```

Comment: why do you need to write a separate  function and not simply use c.Errorf("%v", err) ?

Comment: Also, os.Error is ancient (pre-Go 1).

Comment: @mihai I think it's just an example illustrating that if you had to call another method, you would pass the context in. Regardless it's a response to Nick Siderakis' comment so I'm not sure why this is posted as an answer.